# Time difference using javascript

Tags: javascript

What would be the code for finding the time difference between two different times which are in a 12hr format using javascript. I am using these two time fields in my dynamic gridview .

```
 var gridNew = document.getElementById("<%= Gridview1.ClientID %>");
            if (gridNew.rows.length > 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < gridNew.rows.length - 2; i++) {
                    var frombox = document.getElementById("Gridview1_txtFrom_" + (i));
                    var tobox = document.getElementById("Gridview1_txtTo_" + (i));
                      if(frombox.value<=tobox.value){
                        alert("Enter valid time set");
                        return false;
```

Comment: can you show some code, share a fiddle?

Comment: here is  the code u asked for

Comment: You could at least show the format of the times.

Answer (score 3):

Here' how you can get milliseconds time difference between two custom dates.

```
Math.abs(new Date(firstDateString).getTime() - new Date(secondDateString).getTime());
```

If you have problems parsing/converting to `Date`, consider using a library like date.js or [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

With moment you could do something like this:

```
var diff = moment('3:30','HH:mm').diff(moment('3:20','HH:mm'));
```

If you need am / pm:

```
var diff = moment('3:30 pm','HH:mm a').diff(moment('3:20 am','HH:mm a'));
```

Here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqc3gx5o/)

Comment: i wanted the different between two times

Comment: But this is exactly what his code does, could be more specific or give an example?

Comment: @Timon.Z THERE are 2 times 9:00 am and 1:00 pm

Comment: 1st being th start and second the end time.

Comment: how do i evaluate whether the condition mentioned in my code holds true for a particular date

Comment: the condition being that end time > start time

Comment: I updated the answer, it looks like you have parsing/conversion issue.

Comment: @IvanLeonenko could u pls elaborate on how to do that

Comment: How do you know the Date constructor will correctly parse *firstDateString* given that the OP hasn't indicated what it is?

Comment: @RobG It's better not to pass to Date any other strings except an ISO ones. That's why I recommended to use moment.js or date.js libs because this problem was already addressed. Unless author wants to implement parsing by himself.

Comment: @avinoor I updated answer with momentjs examples. Just reference the library and do some tests. Good luck!

Comment: @IvanLeonenko—ISO 8601 compliant strings aren't correctly parsed by all browsers in use either, so there are no strings that should be passed to the Date constructor (or Date.parse). And the OP says "*times in 12hr format*", not dates.

Comment: @RobG Good to know, so another reason to use mature libs like moment.

Comment: @IvanLeonenko—but there is no need for a 4,000 line library when less than 10 lines of code does the job.

Comment: @RobG If it's only one place in app that uses date/time related calculations then I agree, but normally it depends on project, from my experience there's usually a need to do many custom formatting/parsing/calculations in business apps. So in many cases using libs like momentjs is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Times in JS can be a pain to deal with cross browser, and anyone who has had to debug wierd cross browser behavior can attest to. I have learned than when ever i wanna do anything with dates in JS involve the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) lib.

I was reluctant at first as I thought i can just do most everything myself and roll my own. This is a cuban cigar and no amount of home rolling can cover all the tools moment comes with.

I wont tell you how to fix, just give you the tool...

[moment().diff](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks. But i know nothing about the moment.js library

Comment: This is the right solution, working with times and dates in Javascript can be cumbersome if you don't use any library.

Comment: Simply saying "*Use library X*" is not an answer.

Comment: @RobG - giving someone the tools and the direction to go in is much better than spoon feeding an answer. You learn more and grow more... I didnt simply say use lib x - i gave a damn good reason and a damn good lib for use case. Do you know the difference between safari and chrome and how they handle dates? I didnt until i spent 3 hrs debugging it... moment.js would have saved me this time.

Comment: @avinoor - moment.js is like lodash for dates... Now u do!

Comment: See [*How do I write a good answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While you might think moment.js is a library worth recommending, you should also show how to use it to answer the question. This answer is equivalent to responding to a DOM question with "use jQuery/ext.js/prototype.js/whatever".

Comment: No its not the same... But thanks anyways for the downvote. I gave the tool to use and the method on the tool, not a one line answer.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the format of the times other than to say they're in "12hr format". An algorithm is to parse and convert them to a common unit, say seconds, find the difference, then format it back into whatever units suit.

So if the times are in h:m:s a/p format like "9:42:15 am" and you want the result in a similar format, then the following functions may help.

```js
/*  Convert time in h:m:s a/p format to seconds
**  Seconds component is optional, h:m is OK
**  Tolerates space before am/pm, leading and trailing whitespace
**  Doesn't validate string
**
**  @param {string} s - time to parse
**  @returns {number} time converted to seconds.
*/
function hmsToSeconds(s) {
  var b = s.match(/\d+/g);
  var am = /am\s*$/i.test(s);
  return ((b[0] % 12) + (am? 0:12))*3600 + (b[1]*60) + (+b[2]||0);
}

/*  Convert seconds to time in h:mm:ss format
**  Maintains sign of input (+/-).
**
**  @param {number} s - seconds to convert
**  @returns {string} seconds converted to h:mm:ss.
*/
function secToHMS(s) {
  function z(n){return (n<10? '0' : '') + n}
  var sign = s < 0? '-' : '';
  s = Math.abs(s);
  return sign + (s/3600 | 0) + ':' + z((s%3600 / 60 |0)) + ':' + z(s%60);
}

function getTimeDifference(t0, t1) {
  return secToHMS(hmsToSeconds(t1) - hmsToSeconds(t0)); 
}

document.write(getTimeDifference('11:32 am','12:38:51pm'));
```

Comment: this is pretty close to what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple plugin to get time differences.

https://github.com/gayanSandamal/good-time

import the goodTimeDiff method from good-time.js to your project

```
import {goodTimeDiff} from './scripts/good-time.js'
```

declare an object to give settings like below. let settings = {}

now assign time values to the declared object variable. ***time must be in standard format and must be a string! ***'from' is optional the default value will be the browser current time.

```
let settings = {
    'from': '2019-01-13T00:00:29.251Z',
    'to': '2018-09-22T17:15:29.251Z'
}
```

now calllback the method called goodTimeDiff() and pass the settings object variable as a parameter.

```
goodTimeDiff(settings)
```

Finally assign the method to any variable you want.

```
let lastCommentedTime = goodTimeDiff(timeSettings)
```